# Preventing math mode from parsing macro input as math?

Tags: math-mode, macros

### Basic Problem

I'm trying to produce a command sequence `\m` that

1. Is called from within math mode, with a single argument `list`
2. "Replaces" all instances `,` and `;` in `list` with `&` and `\\` (resp.)
3. Creates a `pmatrix` with output of 1 & 2 as its content

For example, the code

```
\[
    \m{a,b;c,d}\m{x;y}
\]
```

should expand to be equivalent to the following:

```
\[
    \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

After spending more time on this than I should have, I came up with the following partial solution to the problem using `xstring`:

```
\def\foo#1{
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{&}[\result]

    \verbtocs{\bslashes}|\\|
    \expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\result}{;}{ \bslashes }[\result]
}

\begin{document}
    % Fairly complicated matrix input
    \foo{a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}
    \[
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \result
        \end{pmatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

This is close to what I was hoping for, but I haven't come up with a way to use `\foo` as a helper function for `\m` to get exactly what I want. I was thinking that defining `\m` in the preamble by

```
\def\m#1{
    \foo{#1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \result
    \end{pmatrix}
}
```

would work, but then even calling something as simple as `\m{a}` in math mode will produce errors. It looks as though math mode attempts to parse the definition of `\m` instead of letting `\m` fully expand, but my understanding of how this works is too limited to know how to fix my code.

Is there a way to modify the definitions of `\m` and `\foo` to make them do what I want? Can I somehow escape math mode in the definition of `\m` to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method the old-fashioned way, using macros with delimited parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for pmatrix environment

\newtoks\asqltoks
\makeatletter

\def\gobtilundef #1\undef {}

\def\matlabmatrix #1{\asqltoks{\begin{pmatrix}}\@asqlA #1;\undef;}

% \def\@asqlA #1;{\gobtilundef #1\@asqlE\undef\@asqlR #1,\undef,}
% update: simplified to ->
\def\@asqlA #1;{\@asqlR #1,\undef,}

\def\@asqlB #1;{\gobtilundef #1\@asqlE\undef
                \asqltoks\expandafter{\the\asqltoks \\}\@asqlR #1,\undef,}

\def\@asqlE\undef #1\undef,\undef,{%
    \asqltoks\expandafter{\the\asqltoks\end{pmatrix}}\the\asqltoks }

\def\@asqlR #1,{\asqltoks\expandafter{\the\asqltoks #1}\@asqlS }
\def\@asqlS #1,{\gobtilundef #1\@asqlZ\undef
                \asqltoks\expandafter{\the\asqltoks &#1}\@asqlS }
\def\@asqlZ #1\@asqlS {\@asqlB }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\matlabmatrix {m}$

$\matlabmatrix {m,n}$

$\matlabmatrix {m,n;p,q}$

$\matlabmatrix {a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}$

\end{document}
```

[image: matrices]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation with `expl3` functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\matlabmatrix}{m}
 {
  \asql_matlab_matrix:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_asql_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_asql_one_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_asql_matrix_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \asql_matlab_matrix:n #1
 {
  % clear the token list variable containing the final data
  \tl_clear:N \l_asql_matrix_tl
  % split the argument at the semicolon
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_asql_rows_seq { ; } { #1 }
  % build one row at a time
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_asql_rows_seq
   {
    \__asql_build_row:n { ##1 }
   }
  % print the matrix
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \tl_use:N \l_asql_matrix_tl
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

% the inner function
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__asql_build_row:n #1
 {
  % split the input at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_asql_one_row_seq { , } { #1 }
  % add the row to the token list variable
  % items are separated by &
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_asql_matrix_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l_asql_one_row_seq { & } { & } { & } }
  % add also the \\ row terminator
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_asql_matrix_tl { \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\matlabmatrix{a,b;c,d}\matlabmatrix{x;y} \\
\matlabmatrix{a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

It's quite straightforward: we first split the argument at semicolons; then each item is split at commas and, row by row, the contents of the matrix is built. Finally the contents is inserted between `\begin{pmatrix}` and `\end{pmatrix}` for printing.

[image]

Comment: although this is very instructive, i hope the author using it isn't intending to submit this for publication in a journal.  there is more and more call for journals to be made available in electronic form, and this may call for conversion to mathjax.  unless i greatly misunderstand the capabilities of mathjax conversion, a journal editor would have to "unwind" the input into more basic latex syntax; at worst, the publisher might simply decide that is too expensive, and send the file out for rekeyboarding from the author's output.  neither is desirable.  better to keep it simple.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What sort of electronic form are you referring to above?  Available as a webpage rather than a "document"?

Comment: I decided to accept unbonpetit's answer because it was based in `xstring` like my original code, but this is a nice example use of `expl3`. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottH. -- perhaps a web page, but also possibly an e-book.  as much as i hope it will be possible to generate competent e-books with (la)tex, that may not be the final choice if mathjax turns out to be easier to re-flow.  (although i doubt it.)  just mentioning the possibilities i've heard as scuttlebut, and also noting that coding of this sort already causes serious production difficulties.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I hadn't thought of e-books.

Answer (score 4):

This code should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,amsmath}
\newcommand*\mmm[1]{%
    \begingroup\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1},&[\result]%
    \StrSubstitute\result{\noexpand;}{\noexpand\\}[\result]%
    \begin{pmatrix}\result\end{pmatrix}\endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\[\mmm{a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}\]

\[\mmm{a}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very nice, and I think I have a better idea from it how to use `\noexpand` with `\expandarg` effectively.

Comment: @egreg - I believe that's because unbonpetit's code doesn't load `amsmath`.

Comment: Yes, sorry: a copy-paste error, I forgot the amsmath package. Thank for editing my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you’re already using [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring), you could just try [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Apparently, `pmatrix` survives an additional `\\` after the last line without adding an extra line (unlike the usual math environments). The additional `&` though has to be removed, this is done by `\@gobblesecondoftwo`.

I have also included a solution that does use TeX’s delimited parameter to split the argument at `;`s and `,`s.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% xparse solution
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\def\@gobblethirdofthree#1#2#3{#1#2}
\def\@gobblesecondoftwo#1#2{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\SplitList;}m}{
 \begin{pmatrix} \ProcessList{#1}\@foo \end{pmatrix}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\@foo{>{\SplitList,}m}{
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobblesecondoftwo
  \ProcessList{#1}\@@foo \\
}
\def\@@foo#1{&#1}

% plain delimited parameters
\newcommand*{\fooo}[1]{%
  \begin{pmatrix}\foo@split@semi#1;\foo@@@split@semi\foo@@split@semi\end{pmatrix}
}
\def\foo@split@semi#1;#2\foo@@split@semi{%
  \foo@split@comma#1,\foo@@@split@comma\foo@@split@comma
  \ifx\foo@@@split@semi#2\expandafter\@gobble\else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{\\\foo@split@semi#2\foo@@split@semi}%
}
\def\foo@split@comma#1,#2\foo@@split@comma{%
  #1
  \ifx\foo@@@split@comma#2\expandafter\@gobble\else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{&\foo@split@comma#2\foo@@split@comma}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\foo{a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}$
$\foo{m}$

$\fooo{a,b,c;d,e_{f,g},h;i,j_{1,e^n},k}$
$\fooo{m}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do string replacement you can just define `,` and `;` to do the right thing in `pmatrix`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\m#1{{%
\mathcode`\,"8000
\mathcode`\;"8000
\begingroup\lccode`\~`\,%
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{&}%
\begingroup\lccode`\~`\;%
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\\}%
\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \m{a,b;c,d}\m{x;y}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with `\m{1_{a,b},c;d,e}}`

Comment: @egreg well don't do that then:-)